# wp_redirect does not work with my url

Tags: wordpress, redirect

```
wp_redirect('http://www.novasoftware.se/WebViewer/(S(onfdgir5pyy4srekwqj5vk45))/design1.aspx?schoolid=82190&code=730786', 301);
```

I have trouble with this I am afraid.

This is the address I want to get to:
http://www.novasoftware.se/WebViewer/(S(onfdgir5pyy4srekwqj5vk45))/design1.aspx?schoolid=82190&code=730786

But this is what the ulr transforms to in the wp_redirect:
http://www.novasoftware.se/WebViewer/Sonfdgir5pyy4srekwqj5vk45/design1.aspx?schoolid=82190&code=730786

I have tried to urlencode the url, but that did not work.
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [WordPress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect), wp_redirect does not exit automatically and needs to be followed by the command *exit*, so your code should look like:

```
<?php
wp_redirect('http://www.novasoftware.se/WebViewer/(S(jkb41kbyejh4q3jiicwexcq2))/design1.aspx?schoolid=82190&code=730786', 301);
exit;
?>
```

**Edit:**

Instead of using wp_redirect(), use header().

Comment: Thanks - I have added that - but it does not solve the problem with the url being altered by wp_redirect.

Comment: Instead of using wp_redirect, try using header(); followed by exit();